# Found plugin pry-remote, but could not require 'pry-remote'

Tags: ruby, readline, pry

When I run `pry` in my terminal, I got this message:

```
Found plugin pry-remote, but could not require 'pry-remote'
dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15/readline.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15/readline.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15/readline.bundle
[1] pry(main)>
```

But I can use pry. Why it require `pry-remote`? If the `readline` has problem, is it necessary to reinstall ruby again?

Comment: are you using a gemfile? What are you trying to run?

Comment: @maxpleaner I just want to run some basic ruby code. When I type `pry` in the terminal, I want to write ruby only. So I didn't use a Gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
gem uninstall pry-remote
```

Then hopefully pry will run

Comment: Thank you. After I run it and run `pry` again, I got many `Ignoring` messages like `Ignoring bcrypt-3.1.11 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bcrypt --version 3.1.11`.

Comment: Sorry, that may have not been the best advice here. Try `gem pristine --all` now